# How to deploy a nameko microservice

Tags: microservices, nameko

I've been reading through the nameko docs, and it is all good and clear, except for one part.
How do you actually deploy your nameko microservice?
I mean, it is clear how we deploy RESTful APIs in flask_restful, for instance. But with nameko?
If two microservices should communicate, how do we move them into the "listening" state?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem.
For each nameko service you define `AMQP_URI` constant that point to your RabbitMQ instance.
If each of your services have the same AMQP_URI, it make possible communication through sending rpc calls (where you have a queue per service endpoint) or using pub/sub messaging because service use the same RabbitMQ instance.

You can also have HTTP REST API. You must define endpoint in nameko service with `http` decorator (see example here: https://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built_in_extensions.html). In your confguration you have to define PORT for you web server, e.g. port 8000: `WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0:8000`. And make this port accessible for the World.